# String.Replace does not work for HTML entity reference

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I'm trying to replace `'` with its HTML entity reference using the String.Replace function. So `a'a` becomes `a&#8217;a` which is correct, but if I try to make the inverse (from the string above back to `a'a`) the output is always `a&#8217;a`.

I've noticed that if I try to replace only the code `#8217;` without the `&` character everything works fine, so maybe that the `&` character is a part of the problem.

Comment: Please give us some code.

Comment: Perhaps change the title to "C# String.Replace doesn't work *as I expect it*"

Comment: Also, there are multiple quote-like glyphs; I wonder if is it is simply a different code-point

Comment: What is `inverse` method? what is a thing you want to inverse?

Comment: @Saeed, I don't think Jaxer means to call an Inverse() method. I think he means that if String.Replace() is called twice the string should be back to the way it was before String.Replace() was called the first time. Without some code it's hard to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```
string s0 = "a'a";
string s1 = s0.Replace("'", "&#8217;"); 
string s2 = s1.Replace("&#8217;", "'");
```

Could you give us more information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats your problem, this little code works just perfect:

```
        String test = "a&#8217;a";

        Console.WriteLine(test.Replace("&#8217;", "'"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think its is string delimiters i.e ",' are interrupting normal string delimiters.